# what is "FLF",[03]

Tags: java, junit, easymock

I am new to EasyMock and junit  and running one of tests in eclipse and I see this error:
Unexpected method call LdapStudentDAO.findStudentRoles("FLF",[03]): in failure trace. I am not sure what this mean. Thank you.

Comment: can you post the test method?

Comment: Sounds to me like you have a mocked instance of `LdapStudentDAO`, and it has a method `findStudentRoles` that gets called with arguments `"FLF"` (probably a String) and `[03]`, probably a list or array, maybe varargs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please always provide a full example when asking a question. That way we can answer more accurately.

The message means the method `findStudentRoles` with parameters `"FLF"` and `[03]`  of a mock of `LdapStudentDAO` was called and this call wasn't expected by the mock.

Depending on the recording, the method entirely or the the parameters are not matching any recording. Thus this error.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It gave me bit understanding, so is that mean I need to add that call?

Comment: Yes. If it's fine that it's called, you should. Only match exactly the parameters if they are relevant. Otherwise, just use `anyObject()`